# Insert the javaDoc parameters and print them

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a problem that is probably simple, but if I'm starting to program in java language, I'm having great difficulty in this part.

In the java document (JavaDoc) I want to pass the 2 parameters (@param) of the 2 methods and print the result of the operation in output. I've tried several ways, but still not succeeding.

But I have another main class called (Start), in this I want to call the (Operators) class, call the methods and print them.

```
* This class represents an operation
 * @author Pew
 */
public class Operators {


    /**
     * This method performs the sum of the 2 variables
     *@param parameter1
     *@param parameter2
     */
    public void sum(){
        int num1 = 27, num2 = 74, sumInt;
        sumInt = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("The sum result is: " + sumInt);
    }


    /**
     * This method performs the subtraction of the 2 variables
     *@param parameter1
     *@param parameter2
     */
    public void sub(){
        int num1 = 27, num2 = 74, subInt;
        subInt = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("The result of the subtraction is: " + subInt);
    }
```

Comment: You initializes the variables inside your method and not by parameter. You should change to `sum(int num1, int num2)` (analoguous for `sub`) - or name the variables as `parameter1` and `parameter2` as mentioned in the JavaDoc

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You may confuse Javadoc with the actual program code. Java doc is the documentation of your code, explaining what it does, what its limits are, and how to use it. This is conveniently included in comments in your code, as opposed to e.g., a separate Word document. The javadoc tool can pull out these comments and turn them into a html documentation. Your code needs to take the arguments, writing them in the documentation does not help. Your IDE or the javadoc tool should warn you about mismatch in Javadoc and actual methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone for any suggestions and ask that the publication be defined as resolved, because I got the answer I was looking for.

```
    /**
     * This class represents an operation
     * @author Pew
     */

public class Operators {


    /**
     * This method performs the sum of the 2 variables
     * @param num1 The first number to perform the sum
     * @param num2 The second number to perform the sum
     */
    public void sum(int num1, int num2){
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("The result of the sum is: " + sum);
    }


    /**
     * This method performs the subtraction of the 2 variables
     * @param num1 The first number to perform the subtraction
     * @param num2 The second number to perform the subtraction
     */
    public void sub(int num1, int num2){
        int sub = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("The result of the subtraction is: " + sub);
   }
}


public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Operators start = new Operators();

        start.sum(11,34);
        start.sub(11,34);
  }
}
```